# Is there a companion to the book 'A Synopsis of Elementary Results in Pure and Applied Mathematics' by George S. Carr?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation, advice

*[A Synopsis of Elementary Results in Pure and Applied Mathematics](https://archive.org/details/asynopsiselemen00carrgoog)* by George S. Carr is as most of you probably know a book that was famously used by the great mathematician Ramanujan. It is said he proved most of the theorems and formulas in this book before he went off to study at Cambridge University with G. H. Hardy. This is quite a feat given that there are about 6000 formulas and theorems in this book. Given that it's a popular and well known book I'm curious as to whether there has ever been a companion guide (or any other resources) published for this book that contains proofs (or hints and the like) of theorems/formulas in question. I am asking as i'd like to work through a portion of this text. Thanks.

Comment: The key may be out of print now.